# Extract Note Text Format (Bold/Italic/Strikethrough) from iOS OTG Backup

Tags: ios, iphone, backup, reverse-engineering, usb-otg

I am trying to extract content from iOS OTG backup database. I will be able to restore note text from the OTG back. However, I am unable to get the note text format like bold/italic/strikethrough. Is there any way or available pattern for extracting text format?

I made a backup of the iPhone on a MAC pc. Then extract note text/contents from NoteStore.sqlite DB. I followed this tutorial https://www.richinfante.com/2017/3/16/reverse-engineering-the-ios-backup.html#notes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.